# Does rectangular matrix product "left inverse" rule out "right inverse"?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

Given a $n$-x-$d$ (where $d<n$) matrix $A$ with linearly independent columns and another $n$-x-$d$ matrix $B$ (also with linearly independent columns) such that

$$A'B=I_d$$

where the apostrophe means transpose and $I_d$ is a $d$-x-$d$ identity matrix, I'm looking for a concise, straightforward way to show that

$$AB'\neq I_n$$

where $I_n$ is a $n$-x-$n$ identity matrix.

(Also checking in to make sure the second equation is true given the provided information above. I worked it out algebraically for a case with $d=2$ and $n=3$ and it seemed true, but I often make mistakes.)

Assume the elements of $A$ and $B$ are all real and non-zero.

Comment: Hint: one of the products corresponds to a map which goes through a space of smaller dimension in the middle, so it cannot be surjective.

Comment: Counter-example maybe ?

Comment: Have you heard about rank? @ElBazzi A counterexample can't prove that such inverse never exists.

Comment: @Arthur Heard about it, yes, along with column space and dimension, but still wrestling with these ideas, as is immensely obvious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a theorem that says that any time you multiply two matrices $A$ and $B$, the rank of the product $AB$ can't be bigger than the biggest rank among the two factors $A$ and $B$ (there is also a result which says "The rank of $AB$ can't be smaller than...", but that's not as relevant to our problem).

And for each of $A$ and $B$, the rank can't be bigger than the smallest dimension, which in this case is $d$. But the identity matrix $I_n$ has rank $n$, which is larger than $d$. Therefore the product $AB'$, which has at most rank $d$, cannot be the identity matrix.

Comment: Perfect.  Does this theorem have a name, or could you link me to an authoritative source?

Comment: @ben It should be in any book not many pages after the rank is introduced for the first time. I don't think it has a special name, but it goes under the general heading "properties of the rank".